# Spark on a single node: speed improvement

Tags: apache-spark

Is there any sense to use Spark (in particular, MLlib) on a single node (besides the goal of learning this technology)?
Is there any improvement in speed?

Comment: @Stéphane: Compared to a simple sklearn python project without any parallelization of computations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you comparing this to using a non-Spark machine learning system?

It really depends what the capabilities are of the other library you might use.

If, for example, you've got all your training data stored in Parquet files, then Spark makes it very easy to read in those files and work with, whether that's on 1 machine or 100.

Comment: I am comparing with a simple sklearn python project without any parallelization of computations. Or, for instance, a simple R script that uses randomForest library. With my data, these scripts take around 3 hours to provide solution.

Comment: In that case, if your current project only uses 1 CPU, then Spark can help you use multiple CPUs on the same box, but otherwise it's not likely to be significantly faster or slower.